# In Java, can I scan a string and store it as lowercase/uppercase characters regardless of the input

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program that asks for a user to input a string, stating one of three given options. The options are: Small, Medium, Large. Regardless of the type-casing of the word that the user inputs (eg. small, Medium, LaRgE), is there a way so that I can store the string into my variable as just the first letter being uppercase, followed by all lower-cased letters, or even specifically just any combination of lower/uppercase for small, medium, large will end up Small, Medium, or Large, accordingly?

Comment: `String#toUpperCase`/`String#toLowerCase`? You can also use `String#equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: I think , the best way would be using str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2) : JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking for a way to check for equality of two `String`s regardless of their case, not really changing their value. You're looking for `equalsIgnoreCase`. Per Oracle,

> Compares this String to another String, ignoring case considerations. Two strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length and corresponding characters in the two strings are equal ignoring case.

```
String myString = "hello";
System.out.println(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("HELLO")); //true
System.out.println(myString.equalsIgnoreCase("hElLo")); //true
```

Comment: Thanks, new to java, will look into this method!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can grab the first character with `charAt(0)` and then capitalize it with [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29). Then take the `substring` from index `1` and call [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) with something like

```
String a = "smALL";
String out = Character.toUpperCase(a.charAt(0)) + a.substring(1).toLowerCase();
System.out.println(out);
```

assuming you want a canonical representation. For comparison, you might prefer to use [`String.equalsIgnoreCase(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) with something like

```
if ("small".equalsIgnoreCase(a)) {
    // ...
}
```

which is an example of [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). If you don't like them you could use something like

```
if (a != null && a.equalsIgnoreCase("small")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html). It has various methods such as capitalize() , uncapitalize() etc which can format strings to as per your case needs

Answer (score 0):

To ask a user for the string you can do the following:

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userString = input.nextLine();
```

Then to format the string such that the first letter is capitalised:

```
 String userString = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1, name.length()).toLowerCase();
```

---

There are many ways to solve this problem, my solution is just one of the very many.